# how to get current application path in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public XML()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    XmlDocument document_name = new XmlDocument();       
    XmlElement student = document_name.CreateElement("Student");
    XmlElement name = document_name.CreateElement("Chandru");
    student.AppendChild(name);
    document_name.AppendChild(student);
    XmlAttribute id = document_name.CreateAttribute("ID");
    name.SetAttributeNode(id);
    id.Value = "sst5038";
    XmlElement fname = document_name.CreateElement("FName");
    fname.InnerText = "Anjappn";
    name.AppendChild(fname);
    XmlElement mname = document_name.CreateElement("MName");
    mname.InnerText = "Thaiyamuthu";
    name.AppendChild(mname);
    document_name.AppendChild(student);
    document_name.Save(@"D:\student.xml");
}
```

with above code.I create one xml file as code behind in wpf and i save this file in my local disk D:\student.xml

```
 document_name.Save(@"D:\student.xml");
```

But i want to save this xml file (student.xml) in my project file which i am working now.

what should i do for this.

please help me...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Is this the property you're looking for?

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

It works both in WPF and Winforms because its a function in C# and is not specific to WPF or Winforms.

Comment: Again, this will give you the current working directory, which can be different from the application directory. Prefer `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` as stated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

`System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` will help you. Note that the string returned doesn't end with a backslash.

Comment: This will give you the current working directory, which can be different from the application directory. Prefer `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` as stated in the accepted answer.