# How to determine the path that was used to start the current application?

Tags: c#, .net

How can we figure out the filesystem location of the running application?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That would depend on the type of application: console, winforms, wpf, asp.net, windows phone, ... I hope you realize that the fact that you tagged your question with C# is pretty meaningless in this context.

Comment: application.info.path and many other properties will help you

Comment: ... or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025269/c-sharp-executable-executing-directory) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606747/how-to-get-application-path) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362790/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-application-root-directory) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881251/how-to-get-the-path-of-appwithout-app-exe) ... if the site suggests to check whether your question has been asked before, **please do so**.

Answer (score 2):

If you work on Console use this

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

or on Windows Forms use

```
Application.StartupPath
```

Comment: @TravisBanger: Your question does not give any indication of that. You should add the appropriate tags. Pro tip: With the WPF reference added, your question is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application) and [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926506/how-to-get-current-application-path-in-wpf).

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];`